# XMPP library for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am looking for open source XMPP library for Windows Phone 8.1. I have already tried agsXMPP but i am having some trouble using it, i guess it doesn't support WP8.1.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you can find more libraries from here: http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/

Comment: Please post some relevant content from the link.

Comment: For example,
jabber-net,
MatriX.
I had no experience with them but they say they will work with WP 8.1

Comment: I have already tried that link. Apparently  non of them seems to work with WP 8.1 .